# How should I go about discovering the purpose for these mystery pipes in my separated garage?

Tags: plumbing, garage

My house has a separate garage which a prior owner used as a workshop. It has a separate fuse box and electricity meter, but no water or gas. In one corner there are what look like stubbed out water pipes and a drain, but there is no indication inside my house of a connection. Firstly what do these look like? And second how can I (affordably) detect the type of pipe and where they go (if anywhere)?[image: mystery pipes]

Comment: The two small pipes should match to  two pipes leading out though a wall in your house.  Might be covered by a ceiling.  The big one is a drain type, but with it not capped might not connected yet to your drain(digging might be your future).

Comment: Paint has been slopped on, but two capped copper pipes are presumably hot and cold water, and that makes the large one presumably drain. Given the drain is open, pour water down it to see if it fills up, or keeps going away. Alternatively, ignore all of them. If the copper pipes are (as it appears) in direct contact with concrete, you may have a corrosion issue in the furture causing you to need to find where they connect to the water supply pipes, if they are connected to the water supply somewhere, and it's not via valves that are currently shut off.

Comment: Looks like thinwall conduit for electric wire. A few could have been placed when the concrete was poured for possible future use. Cheap to place before concrete is poured.

Comment: @crip659 outside of this building there is no indication of any connections. The nearest building, my house, has no pipes leaving the building.

Comment: @blacksmith37 the fact they are capped made me think it was for water, but you could be right

Comment: Water pipes(all pipes really) are usually buried in the ground to prevent freezing/damage.